# Error al tratar de añadir un nuevo usuario

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Hola estoy tratando de añadir un nuevo usuario a traves de un registro en una API usando mongodb y node.js

pero al tratar de añadir el usuario me sale el siguiente error en la consola:

MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: flitterApp.users index: id_1 dup key: { id: null }

Alguien me podra ayudar a corregirlo?

Comment: Hola Emily, sería buena idea que nos mostraras tu código para ver que puede estar fallando, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Comment: pon el código de la API que usas y como estás haciendo uso de ella